# Trying to extend User to UserProfile in form Django

Tags: python, django, forms

Hi I am having serious trouble this getting this form to work. When I try to run my program it gets to print("4") then throws the error

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: slug_trade_app_userprofile.user_id
```

To be clear the new user i am creating doesnt exist prior to clicking submit on the form

It seems like profile is trying to create a new user again but since (i think) user created a new user, that user already exists its throwing the error. HELP!!

Views.py

```
def signup(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        print("1")
        user = user_form.save(commit=False)
        user.save()

        print("2")
        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        print("3")
        profile.user = user
        print("4")
        profile.save()
        print("5")

        user = authenticate(username=user_form.cleaned_data['email'],
                            password=user_form.cleaned_data['password1'],
                            )

        login(request, user)
        return redirect('/home')
else:
    user_form = UserForm()
    profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    return render(request, 'slug_trade_app/signup.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
```

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/profile_pictures', blank=True )
bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
on_off_campus = models.CharField(max_length=3,
                            default="on",
                            choices=CAMPUS_STATUS)
```

forms.py

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField(required=False)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = (
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'password1',
        'password2',
    )

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.username = self.cleaned_data['email']
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

    if commit:
        user.save()

    return user


class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('profile_picture', 'bio', 'on_off_campus')
```

Comment: The error seems to be saying that there is already an entry in UserProfile for the user_id.

I'd try recreating the database to make sure there is no orphaned data in either of the User or UserProfile tables (from the dev process or manual manipulation?) then try running your code again.

Comment: hey lukewarm. I have actually tried that a number of times. ive also tried with completely impossible values like kjasdfjasdlkfj@lajsdfl;kajsfl.com for the email. still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try `profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user)` Also I believe `profile.user = user` should be `profile.user = request.user` otherwise user refers to the user form not the user instance

Comment: Just tried that and got "'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'"

Comment: @Midi_ did you get this figured out?